# Dataset fitting with proper curve

Tags: plotting

```
stab1 = {{168, 0.3227}, {169, 0.2982}, {170, 0.2706}, {171, 
    0.236}, {171.5, 0.213}, {172, 0.183}, {173, 0.075}, {172.5, 
    0.144}, {172.8, .109}, {173.1, 0.049}, {173.15, 0.032}, {173.2, 
    0}};
```

I have this data set. I could not fit the curve properly.

I have used

```
line1 = Fit[stab, {1, x^2, x^4}, x];
```

However when I do

```
Show[Plot[{line11}, {x, 168, 178}, PlotRange -> {{168, 178}, {.0, .7}}, 
 Frame -> True], ListPlot[stab1]]
```

[image]

What could be the proper fit?

Comment: asking what functional form is appropriate for your data is really out of scope of this site. It really requires some knowledge of the physics behind the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
line1 = Fit[stab1, x^# & /@ Range[0, 10], x];
```

[image]

Comment: [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) has the attribute [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) so you can use `x^Range[0,10]` rather than `x^#&/@Range[0,10]`